# Creating Model on GRCC TCG

Tags: java, tomcat, oracle-apps, oracleapplications

I am working with oracle GRCC Tcg Application version 8.6.4. I have created business object successfully on this Tcg application. After that I have created a model using that business object. While I'm trying to save the model, the following exception will be thrown..can anybody please me to clear the following exception.

2012-12-12 11:50:08,924 ERROR [Thread-51] TcgEtlAbstractService:462 Failed getting nodes to ETL from the subgraph
oracle.apps.grc.domain.exception.MetaGraphCycleException
        at oracle.apps.grc.domain.ontology.QuadStoreManager.buildMetaGraph(QuadStoreManager.java:251)
        at oracle.apps.grc.appservices.TcgEtlAbstractService.getOntClassesByDS(SourceFile:411)
        at oracle.apps.grc.appservices.TcgEtlAbstractService.getOntClassesByDS(SourceFile:384)
        at oracle.apps.grc.appservices.TcgEtlJob.updateParams(SourceFile:878)
        at oracle.apps.grc.appservices.TcgEtlJob.runJob(SourceFile:271)
        at oracle.apps.grc.scheduler.job.AbstractJob.run(SourceFile:410)
        at oracle.apps.grc.common.executor.GrcExecutor$GrcRunnable.run(GrcExecutor.java:177)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
2012-12-12 11:50:08,924 WARN  [Thread-51] DataSourceDaoSpr:221 Locale Key was null in UserPreferences will set to default
2012-12-12 11:50:08,956 DEBUG [Thread-51] DataSourceDaoSpr:250 Loaded 2 from the cache.
2012-12-12 11:50:09,226 DEBUG [Thread-51] QuadStoreManager:189 ********************* Start buildMetaGraph: 864300_864400 *******************
2012-12-12 11:50:09,308 DEBUG [Thread-51] QuadStoreManager:224 *************************************************************
2012-12-12 11:50:09,309 DEBUG [Thread-51] QuadStoreManager:225  **METAGRAPH buildMetaGraph triple count: 1333
2012-12-12 11:50:09,311 DEBUG [Thread-51] QuadStoreManager:242 **************************************************************
2012-12-12 11:50:09,312 DEBUG [Thread-51] QuadStoreManager:243 ** buildMetaGraph node count: 665
2012-12-12 11:50:09,838 ERROR [Thread-51] QuadStoreManager:247 Cycles detected :

2012-12-12 11:50:09,839 ERROR [Thread-51] TcgEtlJob:942 Exception in checkForEtlCompleted
oracle.apps.grc.domain.exception.MetaGraphCycleException
        at oracle.apps.grc.domain.ontology.QuadStoreManager.buildMetaGraph(QuadStoreManager.java:251)
        at oracle.apps.grc.appservices.EtlObjectAppenderService.getNodeOntologyVersionPairsToEtl(SourceFile:577)
        at oracle.apps.grc.appservices.TcgEtlJob.updateParams(SourceFile:928)
        at oracle.apps.grc.appservices.TcgEtlJob.runJob(SourceFile:271)
        at oracle.apps.grc.scheduler.job.AbstractJob.run(SourceFile:410)
        at oracle.apps.grc.common.executor.GrcExecutor$GrcRunnable.run(GrcExecutor.java:177)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
2012-12-12 11:50:09,840 ERROR [Thread-51] AbstractJob:446 Error occurred in concrete job implementation
java.lang.RuntimeException: oracle.apps.grc.domain.exception.MetaGraphCycleException
        at oracle.apps.grc.appservices.TcgEtlJob.updateParams(SourceFile:943)
        at oracle.apps.grc.appservices.TcgEtlJob.runJob(SourceFile:271)
        at oracle.apps.grc.scheduler.job.AbstractJob.run(SourceFile:410)
        at oracle.apps.grc.common.executor.GrcExecutor$GrcRunnable.run(GrcExecutor.java:177)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
Caused by: oracle.apps.grc.domain.exception.MetaGraphCycleException
        at oracle.apps.grc.domain.ontology.QuadStoreManager.buildMetaGraph(QuadStoreManager.java:251)
        at oracle.apps.grc.appservices.EtlObjectAppenderService.getNodeOntologyVersionPairsToEtl(SourceFile:577)
        at oracle.apps.grc.appservices.TcgEtlJob.updateParams(SourceFile:928)
        ... 4 more
2012-12-12 11:50:09,840 DEBUG [Thread-51] JobStatusService:363 Calling JobDao.updateJobStatus

2012-12-12 11:50:09,960 DEBUG [pool-9-thread-4] PeriodicCheckMonitorStrategy:83 290 ERRORED
2012-12-12 11:50:09,960 DEBUG [pool-8-thread-1] JobStatusMonitor:186 oracle.apps.grc.appservices.TcgEtlJob@455511cb 290 ERRORED

2012-12-12 11:52:20,323 ERROR [http-8080-3] PreAnalysisJobValidationService:290 Pre-Analysis data validation failed with following errors:
2012-12-12 11:52:20,324 ERROR [http-8080-3] PreAnalysisJobValidationService:296 Error Code: CAN_NOT_RUN_ANALYSIS_DUE_TO_ETL_FAILURE DEV
2012-12-12 11:52:20,324 DEBUG [http-8080-3] ReasonerServiceImpl:1959 PreAnalysisJobValidationService.canRunAnalysis returned error codes

why this exception occured?
Any help is appreciated..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi my problem has been solved..i just restarted my tomcat the metagraph cycle exception couldn't occur.but this time the log file only shows  the following.
2012-12-13 11:31:56,759 ERROR [http-8080-3] PreAnalysisJobValidationService:290 Pre-Analysis data validation failed with following errors:
2012-12-13 11:31:56,759 ERROR [http-8080-3] PreAnalysisJobValidationService:296 Error Code: CAN_NOT_RUN_ANALYSIS_DUE_TO_ETL_FAILURE DEV
2012-12-13 11:31:56,759 DEBUG [http-8080-3] ReasonerServiceImpl:1959 PreAnalysisJobValidationService.canRunAnalysis returned error codes.